# Randomly Selecting an Image to Display in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error

I am trying to randomly select an image to display in ReactJS (**NOT React Native**). I was trying to base this off of another question, but I am confused and unsure how to fix this error. Here is my code in `RandomWelcomePicture.js`. I am kind of new to this, so sorry if this is an easy fix.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import image2019_0201 from '../images/2019_0201.jpeg';
import image2019_0202 from '../images/2019_0202.jpeg';
import image2019_0203 from '../images/2019_0203.jpeg';

const images = [
    image2019_0201,
    image2019_0202,
    image2019_0203,
];

class RandomWelcomePicture extends React.Component {
    state = { currentImageIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length }
  
    componentDidMount() {
      this.changeImage();
    }
        
    changeImage = () => {
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
      this.setState({
        currentImageIndex: randomNumber
      });
    } 
    render() {
      return (
        <image
          source={images[this.state.currentImageIndex]}
          //style={styles.imageStyle}
        />
      )
    }
  }
```

Here is my error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/RandomWelcomePicture.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: RandomWelcomePicture.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (13:74)

  11 |
  12 | class RandomWelcomePicture extends React.Component {
> 13 |     state = { currentImageIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length }
     |                                                                           ^
  14 |   
  15 |     componentDidMount() {
  16 |       this.changeImage();
```

But I don't think there should be a comma there. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: You cannot have a `componentDidMount` method outside a `class`

Comment: `componentDidMount` is a method on a `React.Component` class. You currently have this method outside of the class which is why you have a syntax error. You also need a `render` method in your class that returns JSX

Comment: @JohnRuddell I don't understand. Where should I move it to?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't understand. Where should I move it to?

Comment: I see you edited it and moved `componentDidMount`. But by looking at the error message and the line number of where the error message is... you can see it was in the wrong place when the error happened

Comment: What you have now is somewhat correct, but you still dont have a `render` method... and a react class will throw an error if you dont have one

Comment: @JohnRuddell what do you mean. I don't have a specific `render` method in my other component and it runs perfectly. I moved things around and still have the semicolon error

Comment: Ah, I see. The issue is you're conflating a class and a functional component. A functional component doesn't have methods on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241318/discussion-between-325-and-john-ruddell).

Comment: I wrote out an answer as its too hard to explain over chat or comments, Let me know if the code is confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is conflating both a `React.Component` class and a functional component in one. Lets look at the code line by line to see this more clearly

```
export default function RandomWelcomePicture() {
// -------------^---------------- functional syntax (its a function)
    componentDidMount() {
// ---------^---------------- class syntax (defining a method)
        this.changeImage();
      }
      
  changeImage = () => {
// ---^---------------- class syntax (defining a method)
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    this.setState({
// ---^---------------- class syntax (setState)
      currentImageIndex: randomNumber
    });
  } 

  return (
// -^---------------- functional syntax (return jsx vs render method)
    <Image
        source={images[this.state.currentImageIndex]}
        style={styles.imageStyle}
    />
  )
  
}
```

Now lets look at how we can change this to work in a functional way and a class component way

#### Functional Component

You dont need to have a componentDidMount to do what you're tying to do here.. just pass that as an initial value to your state.

```
export default function RandomWelcomePicture() {
  const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length))
  const changeImage = () => {
    const randomNumber = ;
    setCurrentImageIndex(randomNumber);
  }
  useEffect(() => changeImage(), [])

  return (
    <Image
        source={images[currentImageIndex]}
        style={styles.imageStyle}
    />
  )
}
```

if you really do need a componentDidMount in a functional component you should do this

```
useEffect(() => changeImage(), []) // empty array means this effect only runs once which is the same thing as componentDidMount
```

#### Class Component

```
class RandomWelcomePicture extends React.Component {
  state = { currentImageIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.changeImage();
  }
      
  changeImage = () => {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    this.setState({
      currentImageIndex: randomNumber
    });
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <Image
        source={images[this.state.currentImageIndex]}
        style={styles.imageStyle}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! One last question... I don't think anything is calling changeImage because none of the three images are appearing when I load the page.

Comment: ``` 
export default function RandomWelcomePicture() {
    const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length))
    const changeImage = () => {
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
      this.setState({
        currentImageIndex: randomNumber
      });;
      setCurrentImageIndex(randomNumber);
    }
  
    return (
      <image
          source={images[currentImageIndex]}
          // style={styles.imageStyle}
      />
    )
  }
 ```

Comment: Like I said in the answer, if you want to call that method with a componentDidMount then use the `useEffect` I put in there. but you shouldn't need to if the state has a default value.

Comment: I ended up not using the componentDidMount. I don't have to use it if there is an alternative

Comment: sorry what I mean is if you want to call that `changeImage` method on your functional component then use this `useEffect(() => changeImage(), [])`

Comment: when I copy and paste the Class Component method, I still get a similar error `Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: RandomWelcomePicture.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (16:74)

  14 |
  15 | class RandomWelcomePicture extends React.Component {
> 16 |     state = { currentImageIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length }` I added this line `useEffect(() => changeImage(), [])` before the RandomWelcomePicture class

Comment: `useEffect` is functional not class. And it can only be defined inside of a React functional component. if you put it outside that will throw an exception

Comment: The only thing that should be outside of your component is the hardcoded images constant.

Comment: I went ahead and put the `useEffect` in the proper place so you can see where it should be used

Comment: useEffect is not defined??? (copied from your example) ``` 

export default function RandomWelcomePicture() {
    const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length))
    const changeImage = () => {
      const randomNumber = 2;
      setCurrentImageIndex(randomNumber);
    }
    useEffect(() => changeImage(), [])
  
    return (
      <image
          source={images[currentImageIndex]}
          //style={styles.imageStyle}
      />
    )
  }```

Comment: .... you shouldn't need me to write out every single detail. a simple google search can help you here.. you should really read up on React fundamentals though. `import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'`